# DD4T 2.0 Java Spring MVC: How to fetch the component field value when it has multiple keywords as its values?

Tags: dd4t, java, keyword

In ViewModel class I am not able to fetch the field values; the field has multiple keywords as its value (say keyword1 and keyword2). Below is the snapshot of the

[image]

In ViewModel class I tried to use variable type as KeywordField  as suggested in http://blog.trivident.com/viewmodel-functionality-in-dd4t-2-0-for-java-part-ii-creating-viewmodels/ but it gives below Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.KeywordField field com.web.cms.model.PackageBundle.bonusItem to org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.KeywordImpl
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at org.dd4t.databind.builder.AbstractModelConverter.setFieldValueOnField(AbstractModelConverter.java:94)
    at org.dd4t.databind.builder.AbstractModelConverter.setFieldValue(AbstractModelConverter.java:72)
    at org.dd4t.databind.builder.json.JsonModelConverter.deserializeGeneric(JsonModelConverter.java:296)
    at org.dd4t.databind.builder.json.JsonModelConverter.buildField(JsonModelConverter.java:208)
    at org.dd4t.databind.builder.json.JsonModelConverter.buildModelProperties(JsonModelConverter.java:116)
    at org.dd4t.databind.builder.json.JsonModelConverter.convertSource(JsonModelConverter.java:95)
    at org.dd4t.databind.builder.json.JsonDataBinder.buildModel(JsonDataBinder.java:175)
```

Comment: Which version of the CM Template Building Blocks are you using? Are you publishing out XML ?

Comment: Hi Raimond; CM TBB version is DD4T 2.0.1 beta and we are publishing  as JSON. Its just converted to XML format for better readability/debug here.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I will investigate shortly. Can you also tell me how the field is defined in the ViewModel ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your Keyword Json structure should look something like this:

```
"Color" : {
    "Name" : "Color",
    "Value" : "Blue",
    "Values" : [ "Blue", "Red", "White" ],
    "NumericValues" : [ ],
    "DateTimeValues" : [ ],
    "LinkedComponentValues" : [ ],
    "FieldType" : 3,
    "CategoryName" : "Colors",
    "CategoryId" : "tcm:7-1020-512",
    "XPath" : "tcm:Metadata/custom:Metadata/custom:Color",
    "KeywordValues" : [ {
      "Description" : "",
      "Key" : "",
      "TaxonomyId" : "tcm:7-1020-512",
      "Path" : "\\Colors\\Blue",
      "ParentKeywords" : [ ],
      "MetadataFields" : { },
      "Id" : "tcm:7-2116-1024",
      "Title" : "Blue"
    }, {
      "Description" : "",
      "Key" : "",
      "TaxonomyId" : "tcm:7-1020-512",
      "Path" : "\\Colors\\Red",
      "ParentKeywords" : [ ],
      "MetadataFields" : { },
      "Id" : "tcm:7-2114-1024",
      "Title" : "Red"
    }, {
      "Description" : "",
      "Key" : "",
      "TaxonomyId" : "tcm:7-1020-512",
      "Path" : "\\Colors\\White",
      "ParentKeywords" : [ ],
      "MetadataFields" : { },
      "Id" : "tcm:7-2115-1024",
      "Title" : "White"
    } ]
```

If this is not OK, then you need to check your field type in the Schema and check with which version of the DD4T TBBs you are rendering content.

If that is OK, then the next step is to define the property correctly in your view model. Since you are adding multiple Keywords, the field is *multi-value*, which means you must enclose the individual keywords in a List:

```
@ViewModelProperty(entityFieldName = "Color")
private List<Keyword> color;

public List<Keyword> getColor () {
    return color;
}

public void setColor (final List<Keyword> color) {
    this.color = color;
}
```

If you debug this, then the actual values come out as as List of KeywordImpls:

[image: Keyword List]

Subsequently, you can then use the view model in your view as follows:

```
<c:if test="${!empty event.color}">
    <c:forEach items="${event.color}" var="colorKeyword">
        <c:out value="${colorKeyword.title}" />
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Hi Raimond; The JSON structure is same as you mentioned but each keyword entry is displayed twice under "KeywordValues" section of JSON and thus in the List<Keywords> of ModelView Class it will give a list with duplicate entry for each keyword value. 
To overcome this issue I was looking a way to fetch keywords from "Values" section of JSON because that does not have duplicate entries.

This seems to be a bug in DD4T 2.0.1 what is the simplest way to fix this bug.

Comment: Can you update your POM to use version 2.0.2 and see what happens ?